# wp_tag_cloud() and the_taxonomies() work but not the_tag()

Tags: posts, loop, tags

wp_tag_cloud() and the_taxonomies() work in a widget I built but I can not get the_tags() to work.

I want to display the tags assigned to the current post. I built a widget to do this. the widget works fine but as I mentioned, wp_tag_cloud() and the_taxonomies() will display.

I have tried every possible code snippet I could find.

Whats happening and do I display the posts tags?

Answer (score 1):

[`the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) only work within the loop;

possibly try to use [`wp_get_post_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags) where you can pass the post ID

Answer (score 1):

I could not see the forest between the trees.

I was dealing with a custom taxonomy and solved the problem with get_the_terms().

```
    $kw_tags = '';
    $tags    = get_the_terms( $pid, 'place_tags' );
    $xt          = 1;

    if ($tags && ! is_wp_error($tags)) {
        ?><h4><?php echo get_option('tag_cloud_title'); ?></h4><?php
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $kw_tags = $tag->name;
            ?>
            <span class="tag-widget"><a href="<?php ?>" title="<?php ?>"><?php echo $kw_tags; ?></a></span>
            <?php
            $xt++;
        }
    }
```